# getting data null on registerForActivityResult

Tags: kotlin, android-intent, android-camera

So everything is worling good camera is opening and also permission dialog is opening if there i no permission, but the image is not getting displayed in the image view. because i am getting null on result.data?.data

This is my function to create path for image captured and to open camera

```kotlin
        fun displayCamera(activity: Activity) {
        val destPath: String? = Objects.requireNonNull(
            Objects.requireNonNull(activity).getExternalFilesDir(null)!!
        ).absolutePath

        val imagesFolder = File(destPath, activity.resources.getString(R.string.app_name))
        try {
            imagesFolder.mkdirs()
            val imgFile = File(imagesFolder, Date().time.toString() + ".jpg")
            val imagePath = FileProvider.getUriForFile(
                activity, "com.example.shoppinglist" + ".provider", imgFile
            )
            val intent = Intent(ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE)
            intent.putExtra(EXTRA_OUTPUT, imagePath)
            cameraResult.launch(intent)
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            e.printStackTrace()
        }
    }
```

2.This is my registerForActivity Result variable

```kotlin
          private val cameraResult = registerForActivityResult(
        ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult()
    ) { result: ActivityResult ->
        if (result.resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            binding.profilepic.setImageURI(result.data?.data)
        }
    }
```

3.This is the code where i am calling this function on button click

```kotlin
         if (checkPermissions(this@RegistrationActivity)) {
                    displayCamera(this@RegistrationActivity)
                } else {
                    requestPermission(requestMultiplePermissionLauncher)
                }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code seems to be fine but sometimes there are issue with the `FileProvider` if you are integrating it with the static package name and storage permission as well with different android versions.

You can try the below code which is working fine. I have saved the image bitmap to the storage and fetch the absolute path as `imagePath` and after fetching the path i am setting the same inside `imageView`.

Just change your code with the below code.

```
private fun displayCamera() {
    val intent = Intent(ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE)
    cameraResult.launch(intent)
}

cameraResult = registerForActivityResult(
        ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult()
    ) { result: ActivityResult ->
        if (result.resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            val imageBitmap = result.data?.extras?.get("data") as Bitmap
            val imagePath = saveImageToStorage(imageBitmap)
            // Here you can insert this imagePath into your room database.
            binding.profilepic.setImageURI(Uri.parse(imagePath))
        }
}

private fun saveImageToStorage(bitmap: Bitmap): String? {
    val timeStamp = SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss", Locale.getDefault()).format(Date())
    val imageFileName = "JPEG_$timeStamp.jpg"
    val storageDir: File? = getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES)

    return try {
        val imageFile = File(storageDir, imageFileName)
        val fos = FileOutputStream(imageFile)
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 90, fos)
        fos.close()
        imageFile.absolutePath
    } catch (e: IOException) {
        e.printStackTrace()
        null
    }
}
```

Comment: what i am trying to do here is setiing profile image in imageview and also save the the image in users device and the path to room data base so that i can set the profile picture automatically when the user is already logged in. simply fetching the path from room and load it to image view via glide

Comment: I have made some changes as per your requirement, Hope it will make up to your requirement.